# $u_t=u_{xx}+u$. How do you solve this partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, online-resources

> Find all solutions of the form $u(x, t) = \phi(x−ct)$ (so called
>   travelling waves) for the partial differential equation $$u_t = u_{xx}
> + u$$

I just had my first two lectures on partial differential equations and the explanations from our lecturer are not really working for me. Can someone show me how to solve a partial differential equation like the one in my question, or even better, refer me to a good source for beginners? Does the equation I mentioned above have a special name or a special "ansatz" to find solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute the suggested form into the equation. You should get

$$-c\phi' = \phi'' + \phi$$

which is an ODE. I hope you can solve it. Just keep in mind that a solution is a function of $x - ct$.

Comment: Yes I can solve that. This seems so simple now. Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick follow up question. Solving the equation above gives me $$\phi(x)=k_1 e^{-\frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{c^2-4}+c)x}+k_2 e^{\frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{c^2-4}-c)x}$$

Can that be correct? When solving the ODE $-c \phi=\phi''+\phi$ do I have to consider that $\phi$ is a function of $x$ and $t$. Wouldn't that mean it is not a ODE anymore?

Comment: $x$ in $\phi(x)$ is not the same $x$ as in the PDE. In terms of PDE it is $x - ct$. The solution of PDE is then $u(x, t) = k_1 e^{-\frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{c^2-4}+c)(x-ct)}+k_2 e^{\frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{c^2-4}-c)(x-ct)}$

Comment: But am I not substituting $\phi(x-ct)$ into my PDE. Why is $\phi$ then only a function of x when I am solving my ODE.

Comment: What I mean is, when I plug in $\phi(x-ct)$, i get: $$-c \phi'(x-ct)=\phi''(x-ct)+\phi(x-ct)$$

Why can I just integrate this with respect to $x$? Do I just pretend $t$ is a constant here ?

Comment: You cannot pretend that $t$ is constant. Think of $x - ct$ as $z$!

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your patience! :)